# MVVM advantage for freelancer developer?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm a freelance developer. Is there any real advantage to use the MVVM pattern?

I know that the MVVM is most used for large teams, because of the great division between design and code.

But what about a freelancer like me? I should use the MVVM pattern anyway, instead of patterns like MVP and MVC?

Comment: This would probably be better served on the programmers stack exchange site.

Comment: Whatever you do, please don't try to force WPF into the archaic ways of winforms (doing everything in code behind). You will fail miserably.

Comment: IMO this depends entirely on project size.  How large of a project are we talking?

Comment: Project size is completely irrelevant, always use MVVM as most of the frameworks out there make it so easy to use it that not using it just doesn't make any sense... there are just too many benefits to MVVM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I think that MVVM goes hand in hand with WPF. When I started learning WPF, it was a nightmare... it's just so different to Winforms for instance. But when I found out about MVVM and started using it with WPF, everything just fell into place.

It makes perfect sense to have a class (view model) that holds *all* of the data that you need for a particular `Window` or `UserControl` (view). That used to be one of my biggest problems... where do I put this bit of data?

Another problem that I had was creating and fully understanding `DependencyProperty` objects and the variety of handlers that they come with. With MVVM, we don't need to worry about these... we can just use normal CLR properties, albeit with a call to the `INotifyPropertyChanged' interface. No longer do I need to worry about setting up a`static`PropertyChangedCallback` handler just to monitor incoming values.

The only difficulty that I found with MVVM was the bit about 'not using the code behind'... but once I discovered that this is more of a request than a rule, then the problem mostly went away. Once I then found out that `Attached Properties` can implement most of the UI event-type functionality that one would normally put into the code behind (such as `MouseDown` events, etc.), then not using the code behind became a whole lot easier too.

For me, this is a simple choice... unless the project is going to be small, I'd always pick MVVM to use with WPF.

Comment: Good answer, and I agree. I do wish it flowed better the other way: that WPF was better-tooled to support MVVM. For example, I'm constantly bitten by the fact that the SelectedItems collection of MultiSelector-derived controls can't  be databound. :S

Answer (score 2):

I think that this depends more on what framework you use and what the client wants. Also I think there are very few cases when you start a project from scratch, most of the time you will work on already existing projects and then is a good idea to follow whatever is already started.

But, if you have no outside constrains and start from scratch, I think that whatever feels most comfortable for you is the best. For me, MVC is good enough for most of the projects.

Answer (score 1):

The MVVM pattern was originally designed for WPF but can be applied to other frameworks to greater or lesser degree. I would advise using the MVVM if using WPF, it makes for cleaner more manageable code and there is little overhead in following this pattern. Not too complicated and definitely not just for large projects, small projects often grow into larger projects and following a mature pattern such as MVVM from the outset rather than retro-fitting at a later date is good practice.