# ERP system event or MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, event-handling

We are in a process of technology selection for enterprise windows application and considering using WPF. We have decided to use WPF since The ability to make very rich UIs. Now the question is whether we should use MVVM or event (MVP).  We are considering to use MVVM because.

1. Layered architecture.
2. Minimize duplicate code.
3. Testability.

Our team is well experience with ASP.net web form and MVC and most of us have web background. Some team members have little bit of windows form application development experience. I know it is little bit of learning curve to learn MVVM and Our architect wants to reuse code as much as possible. Our application is little bit complex and has lot of Grid control. Can someone please guide us regarding this matter? Should we stick in to MVVM or should we go ahead with event base wcf.

If MVVM is suitable for our application what would be the best MVVM Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the recent [MVVM advantage for freelancer developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213444/mvvm-advantage-for-freelancer-developer/18213726#18213726) post. You will see that it has been put on hold because it is a subjective question, just like yours... this *may* happen to yours also.